# jQuery UI draggable doesn't inject when using an ajax content refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Basically I setup a page with a few draggable elements, it worked fine.

I've just added an ajax content refresh that refreshes the div, the elements are inside, every 10 seconds.

After doing this the draggable function no longer works.

I believe this is because the elements that are getting refreshed are on a separate page, and then loaded into the index with ajax.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you

---

**Basic HTML (nothing special here)**

```
<div id="notes">
    <!--Notes Load Here-->
</div>
<div id="loading">
    Loading..
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

**Scripts.js (inc. Document ready)**

```
/* Draggable functionaility */

var a = 3;

$('.postit').draggable(
{
    start: function(){
        $(this).css("z-index", a++);
    },
    stop: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
    var pid = $(this).attr('id');
    var datastring = 'xpos=' + xPos + ' ypos=' + yPos + ' id=' + pid;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savepositions.php",
        datatype: "text",
            data: {positions: datastring}
    });
    }
});

$('.postit').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
    $(this).css("z-index", a++);
});



/* Auto Refresh */
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#notes').hide();
        $('#loading').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#notes').show();
    },
    success: function() {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#notes').show();
    }
});
var $container = $("#notes");
$container.load("notes.php");
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    $container.load('notes.php');
}, 10000);
```

**Notes.php**
For all intents and purposes, this just contains a div with class="postbit"

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps,

Put all your event binders inside one function and then call that function:

```
function wrapper(){
 $('.postit').draggable(
 {
 start: function(){
    $(this).css("z-index", a++);
 },
 stop: function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var xPos = offset.left;
    var yPos = offset.top;
 var pid = $(this).attr('id');
 var datastring = 'xpos=' + xPos + ' ypos=' + yPos + ' id=' + pid;

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "savepositions.php",
    datatype: "text",
        data: {positions: datastring}
 });
 }
});

$('.postit').click(function(){
 $(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
 $(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
 $(this).css("z-index", a++);
});
}
```

then:

```
$(function(){
   wrapper(); // This does the binding on page load
});
```

and then in your ajax success function call:

```
complete: function() {
    wrapper();
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#notes').show();
},
```

Comment: I see what your trying to do, but for some reason it doesnt work.
All my jquery code is inside document ready tags already. But even so I can't get it to behave.

Comment: @OliverEvans Creating the wrapper function outside of the document.ready and then having a call to the function inside your document.ready and ajax callbacks should work.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't seem to work either. 
I've made an example, have I implemented you code correctly?

     |scripts.php: http://pastebin.com/QqFvtr7r
     |index.php: http://pastebin.com/TcSb5zsK
     |notes.php: http://pastebin.com/RwC1C8Sm

Sorry for the pastebins.

Comment: Could you try calling the wrapper after $('#notes').show(); ? There's a very slight chance that might be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either.
Ive just copied the script tags into the page that is added by ajax. (notes.php) and that works to a point. The elements become draggable, but because im technically calling everything twice everything flickers and is less than acceptable.